# Database tables designing for data without fixed structures

Tags: sql, database, database-design, nosql

I have a data structure which looks like:

```
<event name="SomeEventName" time="2018-03-06 09:30:00" owner="SomeOwnerId">
    <param name="param1" value="value1"/>
    <param name="param2" value="value2"/>
    ...
    <param name="paramN" value="valueN"/>
</event>
```

This structure is sends from clients to server, and describes events which happened on client. I need to store every received user event in database.
The problem, is in designing database table structure: every event received from client could have different number of parameters, and of course different values for every param.
Even the same event could have different number of parameters.

So, my question is about database designing for such data structures, which haven't predefined data structure on server side.
How to design database tables for structures like this?
I could change data receive format which comes from client to JSON for example, but i can't change the format itself - it's an "event" with unknown number of parameters.

Maybe i should take a look at NoSQL databases that could store the whole documents in JSON format?

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you go with NoSQL, you could structure your objects as so in an object. The name, time, and owner are all keys as well as data, which is a key with a value of an object that has all the key/value pairs for your params.

```
{
"name": "SomeEventName",
"time": "2018-03-06 09:30:00",
"owner": "SomeOnwerId",
"data": 
{"param1": "value1",
 "param2": "value2",
...}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Am i understand right, there is no ways to design SQL databases for storing data in format that i explained in first post?

Comment: I am not very familiar with SQL databases so I can't help you there